# Marshalling double pointers in C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling, pointer-to-pointer

I have to interact with a provided C library where one of the functions is declared as follows:

`int GetFileList(struct spiflash_file **ptr_spiflash_filelist, int **file_num);`

where `**ptr_spiflash_filelist` is a pointer to a pointer that represent an array of `spiflash_file` structs, and `**file_num` is a pointer to a pointer of the total file counts.

I am having quite the trouble in marshalling those 2 parameters...
This is what I came up with until now:

```
 [DllImport(LibName, SetLastError = true)]
 private static extern int GetFileList(out IntPtr ptr_spiflash_filelist, out IntPtr file_num);
```

This does not throw exceptions nor errors, but when I inspect the two variables I get absurd values ( i.e. on an empty flash the file count is 1790873936...)

I can't understand how to properly do it and it feels like I am missing just a couple steps..

Comment: Looks like you are getting a pointer.  Use PtrToStructure : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=net-8.0

Comment: for the first parameter, ok, but  what about the second? a `out ref` seems to be the correct way, but it ouputs garbage data.

Comment: How do you know how large the array is?

Comment: is `unsafe` code an option here? i.e. `private static unsafe extern int GetFileList(ptr_spiflash_filelist** ptr_spiflash_filelist, int** file_num);` ? Usage would be something like `ptr_spiflash_filelist* ptr = null; int* file_num = null; GetFileList(&ptr, &file_num);`, which *should* leave the two locals initialized

Comment: What value do you get for 2nd number?  What do you expect?  It may not be an integer (32 bits), or unsigned instead of signed.